# Magento 2 UiComponent endless loop spinner

Tags: uicomponent, data-provider

In this case I was trying to create a UI in admin page using UI Component. I got and endless spinner loop.
Here is my code.

view > adminhtml > layout > cscustomersupport_customer_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
         Customer Information
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="customersupport_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

view > adminhtml > ui_component > customersupport_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">customersupport_form.customersupport_form_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">customersupport_form.customersupport_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
            <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">customersupport_form</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="driver_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Ced\CsCustomerSupport\Model\CustomerProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">customersupport_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="mobidelivery/driver/save"/>
                </item> 
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <fieldset name="general">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Model > CustomerProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Ced\CsCustomerSupport\Model;

use MageNative\MobiDelivery\Model\ResourceModel\Driver\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool;

/**
 * Customer Provider
 *
 * @category Class
 * @package  DriverProvider
 * @author   MageNative Core Team <connect@magenative.com>
 * @license  http://magenative.com/license-agreement.txt MageNative LICENSE
 * @link     http://magenative.com/license-agreement.txt
 */

class CustomerProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{

    /**
     * @var \MageNative\Mobinotifications\Model\ResourceModel\Mobinotifications\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var FilterPool
     */
    protected $filterPool;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $blockCollectionFactory
     * @param FilterPool $filterPool
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerFactory,
        FilterPool $filterPool,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $customerFactory->create();
        $this->filterPool = $filterPool;
    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        return $this->collection->getData();
    }

    // public function addFilter(\Magento\Framework\Api\Filter $filter)
    // {
    //     return null;
    // }
}
```

Any idea why is this happening?
[image]

Exception :

> **Fatal error**:  Method
> Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an
> exception, caught Error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter()
> on null in
> **/data/web/wd-magento/vendor/magento/module-ui/Component/Wrapper/UiComponent.php**
> on line **0**

Comment: Hi @HamendraSunthwal, where can I check the log?

Comment: Check your console and network for any errors.

Comment: Ive updated the console log @RizwanKhan

Comment: as per SS of error Jquery is not defined. have you used jQuery directly on line no. 711?

Comment: The jQuery error seems to exist in all pages @RizwanKhan

Comment: Click on that and check the code there, it should be loaded using requirejs